# Kubernetes Service does not work as HTTP proxy

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to make my K8S GKE Service to work with port :80 using this configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-{{ .Release.Name }}
  labels:
    {{- include "release_labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 34.90.xx.xx
  ports:
  - name: proxy
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    {{- include "release_labels" . | indent 4 }}
```

This is a HTTP proxy service.

The above configuration works with `curl --proxy 34.90.xx.xx:80 gajus.com`, but it does not work when port is not specified, i.e. `curl --proxy 34.90.xx.xx gajus.com`.

What is missing to make `curl --proxy 34.90.xx.xx gajus.com` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in curl man page:

```
   -x, --proxy [protocol://]host[:port]
          Use the specified proxy.
[...]

          If the port number is not specified in the proxy string, it
          is assumed to be 1080.
```

Didn't you mean to try something like:

```
curl --header 'Host: fqdn.example.com' http;//1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Interesting! Did not know that.